# Add Spring security Taglib

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-security

I want use spring security taglibs in my jsf project,so I've made ​​the following changes to the project,but I get this Exception: What am I doing wrong here? i use :

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context 
initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)    
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:    
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler

 ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:293)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:311)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:420)
... 49 more
```

**springsecurity.taglib.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
<namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
 <tag>
    <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
    <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
</tag>
<function>
    <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
<function>
    <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
    <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
  <!-- Spring Security -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> 
       <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId> 
       <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>             
   </dependency>
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried searching the Sonatype Maven Repo for the class:

https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;classname~org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler

which returns three artifacts containing this class. I would try updating the version as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```